# List all possible subgroups of $A_4.$ Determine which subgroups of $A_4$ are normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I have a question which is List all possible subgroups of $A_4$. Determine which subgroups of $A_4$ are normal.

Since $|A_4| = 12,$ the order of any proper subgroup of $A_4$ must be an element of $\{2, 3, 4, 6\}.$

We start with the cyclic subgroups of $A_4:$ $$ \{e,(12)(34)\}, \{e,(13)(24)\}, \{e,(14)(23)\}, \{e,(123),(132)\},
\{e,(124),(142)\}, \{e,(134),(143)\}, \{e,(234),(243)\}.$$

Since A4 does not have any elements of order four and
only three elements of order two, we get that the only possible normal subgroup of $A_4$ is $\{e,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}.$

That's all I know!

Comment: See what pairs of generators give you. You can use some of the symmetry inherent in the group to reduce your workload; for example, to see what a pair of $3$-cycles will generate, you really only need to check what, say, $(123)$ and $(124)$ generate, and use that to show what any other pair of $3$-cycles will generate. So ultimately, there's only really a couple of computations to do beyond what you've already done here.

Comment: Hi! Check this out: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_alternating_group:A4